# A_Class cannot be cast to B_Class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I apologize if my file names throw you off.

so the actual error I am getting is:

```
pwnavor.ljv1.Home_Page cannot be cast to pwnavor.ljv1.MainActivity
```

I have no idea what this means and after looking around stacked I have realized it covers a few different things. my app is trying to run an activity that processes a rss feed through recyclerview in a tabbed menu when I get this error. If I run MainActivity on its own it works fine however, when I try to run it in Home_Page I get this error and obviously if I run Home_Page without calling for MainActivity things run smooth aswell. Clearly there is something I am missing. I read in another topic dealing with my situation that using getActivity(); was the way to go however, it does not seem to be working out for me. Is there another way to pull the MainActivity into the tabbed window or do i have to rewrite everything into a fragment?

Files in question.

Home_Page.java

```
package pwnavor.ljv1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home_Page extends AppCompatActivity {



    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home__page);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());



        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);











    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home__page, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";



        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1)
            {

/**=================================================================
 * where my issue starts
 */


                MainActivity parent=(MainActivity) getActivity();

                return new View(parent);


/**
 * ==================================================================
                */


            }
            else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2)
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home__page, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Home);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }
            else
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home__page, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Home);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }


        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }


    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Home";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
package pwnavor.ljv1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(this, recyclerView);
        readRss.execute();

    }


}
```

full stacktrace

```
01/15 14:10:15: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "pwnavor.ljv1/pwnavor.ljv1.Launch_Screen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 6328 on device Nexus_5X_API_23 [emulator-5554]
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/pwnavor.ljv1-2/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is pwnavor.ljv1, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/pwnavor.ljv1-2/lib/x86
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                  [ 01-15 14:10:18.618  6328: 6328 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa202180, tid 6328


                  [ 01-15 14:10:18.619  6328: 6328 W/         ]
                  Process pipe failed

                  [ 01-15 14:10:18.643  6328: 6346 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa202540, tid 6346
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
E/EGL_emulation: tid 6346: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa414b00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
E/EGL_emulation: tid 6346: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa231f80, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae473a00
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: pwnavor.ljv1, PID: 6328
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: pwnavor.ljv1.Home_Page cannot be cast to pwnavor.ljv1.MainActivity
                      at pwnavor.ljv1.Home_Page$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(Home_Page.java:128)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:61
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6328 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

edited with full stacktrace

Comment: please provide full stacktrace

Comment: It means what it says `ClassA` is not an instance of `ClassB` and so you can't cast it that way as it makes no sense. The point at which the error occurs is where the cast is, and that is the problem line.

Comment: thank you, I dont see why i get down voted soo hard for asking a question though. Makes me afraid to even bother asking for help or even learning to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class hierarchy is:

```
class Home_Page extends AppCompatActivity
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

This is similar to the following:

```
class Dog extends Animal
class Cat extends Animal
```

You can cast a `Dog` to an `Animal`, but you can't cast a `Dog` to a `Cat`.

In the same way, you can't cast a `Home_Page` to a `MainActivity`.

Comment: Is there a way to run MainActivity in Home_Page? or do i have to write it so that cat is now a fragment called dog toy and dog runs dog toy?